# Send variable to terminate in middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am trying to send a variable to terminate of middleware from route:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkUserLevel'], function () {
    // my routes
});
```

I can get `checkUserLevel` in handle of middleware but I need to access in terminate method too, what should I do?

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $key)
{
     dd($key); // it returns variable
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
      //I need that variable here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/middleware#terminable-middleware), if you would like to use the same instance of middleware (because by default it is using the fresh instance of middleware) you need to register the middleware as singleton.

You can register it as singleton by adding to your `ServiceProvider`'s `register` method

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(\App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class);
}
```

Then you can use the class' property like the first example of [lorent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002089/7171578)

```php
protected $foo;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->foo = 'bar';

    return $next($request);
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    // because we cannot use `dd` here, so the example is using `logger`
    logger($this->foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```php
protected $key;

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $key)
{
     $this->key = $key;
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
     $this->key; //access property key
}
```

even though this should be passed via request global. Like:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     $request->input('key');
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
      $request->input('key');
}
```

Edited:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkUserLevel'], function () {
    Route::get('/test/{testparam}', function () {
    });
});

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     $request->route('testparam');
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
      $request->route('testparam');
}
```

Comment: $this->key in terminate does not get value, it returns empty

Comment: where are you getting this $key from ? Request or controller ?

Comment: I just pass it to middleware in route and get it in handle , I do not use it controller,my main problem is that in terminate $this->key in empty

Comment: I am well aware where is your problem. Check edited answer

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to access to checkUserLevel in handle and terminate I do not need testParam, because I want to add this structure to other routes too

Comment: yeah, thats ur middleware that u are applying to the grouped routes and not a param. I suggest to read a bit more in documentation.

Comment: read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#terminable-middleware and https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#middleware-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ages old, but you could also use a static property. That saves you from having to register a `singleton`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class MyMiddleware {
    private static $key;

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $key)
    {
         self::$key = ($key); // it returns variable
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
          $key = self::$key;
    }
}
```

This works in my Laravel 5.8 application, don't see why it wouldnt' work anywhere else. Cannot say if there's any reason NOT to do this, but I don't know of one.

I'm using this myself to generate a Cache key in my handle function, and reuse the same key in my terminate function.